# WebControl creates JS object in a <script> tag, how to get the object in the page's JS?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-controls

I've been playing around with making my own WebControls, and am trying to add some AJAX functionality without using MS AJAX. I'm not sure of the best way to pass the JS objects from the WebControl's to the page's script.

I use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource` to get my control's JS to the browser, and I instantiate the JS through the server code like so (RenderEndTag writes out a `<script>` that calls new):

```
public class SearchBox : WebControl
{
    //...
    public override void RenderEndTag(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        //...
        writer.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">new SearchBox($('#" + this.ClientID + "'));</script>");
    }
}
```

Now I need to use the object in a specific page's JS (such as to add a valueChanged handler). How should I go about it? Would a global array with the control ID's as keys work?

Comment: Are you trying to access the SearchBox from a page that has your SearchBox control on it?

Comment: Yes; I create the control in the .aspx, which causes an inline script block to be written out; now I need to access the js object to add handlers and what not.

Comment: Global array could work. I would probably rather end up grabbing the object from the DOM in the parent's page handler functions

Comment: How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, one of the things you could do in your SearchBox's javascript constructor is something like this:

```
var SearchBox = function($element) {
    $element.data("searchBox", this);
}
```

Then you could can easily retrieve this from jQuery again at a later point:

```
var sb = $("#myElement").data("searchBox");
```

Comment: Doh, I didn't even think about attaching the object to the element. Much cleaner than a global array.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of your problem I would do something like this:

```
public class SearchBox : WebControl
{
    public int SearchBoxControlId { get { return this.ClientID;}}
    //...
    public override void RenderEndTag(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        //...
        writer.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">new SearchBox($('#" + this.ClientID + "'));</script>");
    }
}


//Other Parent Page
<uc1:SearchBox id="ucSearchBox" runat="server" />
<script>
    $("#SOMEID").change(function (e) {

        var searchBox = $("#<%= ucSearchBox.SearchBoxControlId %>");

        //Do stuff
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I was trying to get the JS object itself (the one returned by `new`) rather than the html element, which is why I chose rossisdead's answer :)